# Is there a spider / link checker that can start deep inside a login-protected site

Tags: links, web-crawlers, dead-links

We use vendor hosted Blackboard for our distance education courses, but host course multimedia on our own servers. The multimedia server has been moved and the domain has changed. Blackboard DBAs have run queries to update the links in the DB, but we need to make sure they got them all. There are hundreds of thousands of links to check.

I need to be able to login to the blackboard administrator, navigate to the courses section and execute a search to bring up the course list before running the link checker on the links in the search results.

Is there a product or service that does this? I've never used selenium, but I wonder if a scripting solution might be more appropriate. All advice welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are crawlers that can crawl a site which requires login.   This requires that you log into your site using your web browser and export your cookies.  Then you start the crawler with the cookies that you had used to log in and the the crawler crawls the site as your logged in user.

To export your cookies, use Firefox with the [Export Cookies Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/export-cookies/).  Log in to your site and then export your cookies using "Tools" -> "Export Cookies.  Save the file as `cookies.txt`.

The [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) command line crawler can use your `cookies.txt` file to start crawling.

```
wget -r --load-cookies=cookies.txt http://mysite.example.com/
```

`wget` will save the website locally in a directory structure like `mysite.example.com/pages/index.html`  You can then run a link checker against these locally saved files.

Comment: I have used wget in the past, but wasn't familiar with the load-cookies option. I'll try this out and report back!